# Double Graphics Card not working

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently bought a pair of new NVidia GTX550 TIs for my Windows 7 gaming rig. Mobo is a Asustek M2N-E SLI board. I am trying to set up a triple monitor setup, preferably with nVidia Surround.

Currently getting some errors. When monitors are plugged into both cards, Card 2 gives a Code 12 "This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use." When I plug a monitor only into Card 2, card 1 doesn't show up in the Device Manager. When I plug a monitor into only card 1, card 2 gives the code 12 error.

I've updated drivers for the card and the mobo. I'm not sure how to determine if my bios needs upgrading nor how to do so if it does.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using SLI? Or are you using them as two independent cards? 32-bit Windows 7 or 64-bit?

Comment: For BIOS Updates: [Asus' Support page for that board](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM2/M2NE_SLI/#download), Pick Downloads, and an OS. Look under BIOS and BIOS Utilities.  It sounds like you may be having BIOS ROM space issues, and a BIOS update may very well fix that.

Comment: @David: Independent cards, since apparently SLI doesn't support triple monitor layouts. 64bit Windows 7.